# How to solve intent redirection?

Tags: android, android-security

We added option 3 by [Remediation for Intent Redirection Vulnerability](https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/9267555?hl=en)

```
Intent intent = this.activity.getIntent();
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        intent.removeFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        intent.removeFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
    }
this.activity.setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
```

But still rejected our app.
Could anyone help? Thanks.

Comment: Can you share what library and version that you are using ?

Answer (score 2):

Based on the Security measures, you can't use the getIntent() with setResult().

Instead of getIntent(), you go with

```
Intent intent = new Intent(); 
//or give the explicit activity name for that intent( i.e Use Explicit Intent)
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        intent.removeFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        intent.removeFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
    }
this.activity.setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
```